# Page is not wrapping whole web content in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc9pK.png)

I have included snippet of css code of html tag.
content of page is not wrapped, there are some blank space at the end of height and also width

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    zoom: 0.95;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! it's probably because `zoom` property

Comment: Thank you, I got the problem it's in that background property it should not be there